# jQuery slideToggle with click and hide on mouseout

Tags: jquery, onclick, mouseevent, slidetoggle

I have a jQuery navigation which uses `slideToggle` and `slideUp` once I click on another nav element. However I can't quite get this to work the way I want, as I want the nav elements to hide once the mouse has left the child elements which have appeared from the click function.

I tried the below, however when this left the `<h5>` tag the `<ul>` disappeared which makes sense considering the statement below:

```
$('.nav_parent h5').on('click mouseleave', function ()
```

Saying that I'm not sure how to go about this, I've read online about setting a timeout function, which I tried and failed at.

So does anyone have any working examples that they have or can adapt my script to enable this functionality?

My scripts are below or view a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCaQ2/3/)

Thanks in advance!

js/js.js

```
$('.nav_parent h5').click(function () {
  $(this).next('.nav_child').slideToggle();
   $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="header_nav">
        <li class="nav_parent">
            <h5>Reports</h5>

            <ul class="nav_child">
                <li><a href="#" class="mnavlink">Download CSV</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_parent">
            <h5>Build</h5>

            <ul class="nav_child">
                <li><a href="#" class="mnavlink">Build new site</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_parent">
            <h5>Subscriptions</h5>

            <ul class="nav_child">
                <li><a href="#" class="mnavlink">E-Briefings</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_parent">
            <h5>Media Store</h5>

            <ul class="nav_child">
                <li><a href="#" class="mnavlink">Image Store</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css/style.css

```
.nav_parent {
    display:inline-block;
    width:24%;
    background:#FCCC5F;
}
.nav_parent h5:hover {
    background:#FCE49D;
}
.nav_child {
    display:none;
}
.nav_child li {
    line-height:30px;
}
.nav_child li:hover {
    background:#FCE49D;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.nav_parent h5').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).next('.nav_child').stop(true, true).slideDown();
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('.nav_child').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    return false;
});
$('.nav_parent').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).children('.nav_child').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QbALJ/)